# How to get 1 specific site property in SharePoint 2013 REST api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In SP2013, I want to get a specific property I made in sharepoint designer. If I use the url

```
http://mysite/_api/web/AllProperties
```

then I can get all properties including the one I want, but how can I just request for that 1 specific property?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is SharePoint Online than you can use below code.

```
"Property You want": {

"__deferred": {

"uri": "https://c986.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Property You want"

}
```

> SharePoint 2013 introduces a Representational State Transfer (REST)
>   service that is comparable to the existing SharePoint client object
>   models. This allows the developers to interact remotely with
>   SharePoint data by using any technology that supports REST web
>   requests. This means that developers can perform Create, Read, Update
>   and Delete (CRUD) operations from their apps for SharePoint, solutions
>   and client applications, using REST web technologies and standard Open
>   Data Protocol (OData) syntax.

Kindly Check below URL

[How to Get the Properties of a Website in SharePoint 2013 Online Using REST API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-the-properties-of-a-website-in-sharepoint-2013-on/)

Comment: Its not online, its on prem, but I figured it out, I just need `?$select=yourproperty` in the end of the url.

Comment: BTW You haven't mentioned your SharePoint version is online or on-permises so i gave you the solution for SharePoint Online. It will also work.